# Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'TextEditingController'

Tags: flutter, dart

**Here is my code, I want to store data to Firebase Database when user enter button but getting the following error**

```
                       onTap: () {
                        if(_controllershopname.text==''||_controllerstreet.text==''||_controllershopnumber.text==''||_controllercity.text==''||_controllerstate.text=='')
                          {

                            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Please Fill all the fields");
                          }else{
                          DatabaseReference databseRefrence = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("ShopKeeper");

                          databseRefrence.child(widget.number).push().set(
                            {
                              'Name':widget.userName,


                              'ShopName': _controllershopname.text,
                              'ShopNumber':_controllershopnumber.text,
                              'ShopStreet':_controllerstreet.text,
                              'ShopCity':_controllercity.text,
                              'ShopState':_controllerstate.text,
                              'OnlineDelivery':"Yes",
                            });
```

**Here is the error**

E/flutter (26078): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'TextEditingController'
E/flutter (26078): #0      StandardMessageCodec.writeValue (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:392:7)
E/flutter (26078): #1      StandardMessageCodec.writeValue. (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:389:9)
E/flutter (26078): #2      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:379:8)
E/flutter (26078): #3      StandardMessageCodec.writeValue (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:387:13)
E/flutter (26078): #4      StandardMessageCodec.writeValue. (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:389:9)
E/flutter (26078): #5      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-

Comment: Can you please provide more details, the details is not sufficient , I want to see the controller then i can help you out

Answer (score 1):

Did you create instances of your **"TextEdittingControllers"?** If you did, then you should try trimming your text before saving to the database:

```
 onTap: () {
        if(_controllershopname.text==''||_controllerstreet.text==''||_controllershopnumber.text==''||_controllercity.text==''||_controllerstate.text=='')
          {
  
          {

            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Please Fill all the fields");
          }else{
          DatabaseReference databseRefrence = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("ShopKeeper");

          databseRefrence.child(widget.number).push().set(
            {
              'Name':widget.userName,


              'ShopName': _controllershopname.text.trim(),
              'ShopNumber':_controllershopnumber.text.trim(),
              'ShopStreet':_controllerstreet.text.trim(),
              'ShopCity':_controllercity.text.trim(),
              'ShopState':_controllerstate.text.trim(),
              'OnlineDelivery':"Yes",
            });
```